# Should these questions be consolidated?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I've noticed several questions from one user that show very minimal effort, and the user seems to be asking for step-by-step instructions to write his program across several questions. None of them (or any of the user's other questions) have accepted answers, furthering the "minimal effort" theme. Should thees questions be consolidated? Closed? Should something else (or nothing) be done?

- [Sharepoint 2010 grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5100592/866022)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5042156/866022
- [creating document set programmatically in sharepoint server 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076930/866022)
- [zip extraction in sharepoint server 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5141415/866022)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5088009/866022
- [Adding column item as a link in sharepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5074264/866022)
- [Sharepoint Document Library -- Document Set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5065192/866022)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5065937/866022

The titles are not very helpful either (and two different questions share an identical title). Several of them have no answers, and it seems nobody wants to answer these questions because they are poorly written (most have been edited), show minimal effort, and are asked by someone who has never acecpted an answer. Should we do something with these questions? If so, what?

Comment: Wow, he's never even left a *comment* on his answers. He's like a reverse-help-vampire.

Comment: I almost wanted to reject your suggested edits because what really needed to happen was a vote to close or Flag as Very Very Very Very Low Quality.

Comment: @sixlettervariables I'm not sure the improved readability does much for the quality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These questions never were, nor will be useful to anyone except the original poster. Moreover, we can assume from the apathy shown by the original poster towards both their questions and answers, that they too don't believe the questions are useful.

Each of the questions are should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the community has already decided not to answer those. You can vote to close for any of the listed reasons (e.g. duplicate), or simply ignore them.

It seems like the community has already ignored them, probably for similar reasons as those you've outlined, which means the system is probably working as intended.